# Переклад на українську мову "cell" в контексті електронних таблиць

Tags: переклад, from-english, терміни

Відомих мені переклади два: **клітинка**, **комірка**.

**1.Клітинка**

> **клітинка вводу**
>
> Клітинка, в яку підставляються всі значення з таблиці даних. Клітинкою
>   вводу може бути будь-яка клітинка аркуша. ([support.office.com](https://support.office.com/uk-UA/article/%D0%A1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA-%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BC%D1%96%D0%BD%D1%96%D0%B2-Excel-53b6ce43-1a9f-4ac2-a33c-d6f64ea2d1fc))

**2. Комірка**

> Активна комірка – це комірка, у яку відбувається ввід даних і яка
>   виділена чорною рамкою з маркером заповнення ([www.college-chnu.cv.ua](http://www.college-chnu.cv.ua/images/Labu/IKT/06_tablychnyi_protsesor_microsoft_excel.pdf))

@bv. нагадав ще про третій варіант

**3. Чарунка**

> Активна чарунка виділена напівжирною темною рамкою – табличним
>   курсором, який можна переміщувати по таблиці ([intranet.tdmu.edu.ua](http://intranet.tdmu.edu.ua/data/kafedra/internal/distance/lectures_stud/%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%97%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B0/1%20%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%80%D1%81/%D0%9C%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%B0%20%D1%96%D0%BD%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0/%D0%9B%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%86%D1%96%D1%8F%204.%D0%9E%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%20%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%B3%D1%83%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F%20%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%8C%20%D0%B2%20MicrosoftExcel.%20%D0%A5%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%20%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%20%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8E%20Excel.htm))

На мою думку більш зрозумілим і звичним є перший варіант - "клітинка". Однак, хотів би дізнатися який же варіант є найбільш коректний.

Comment: Згідно начальної програми напрямку ПЗ в універистеті ми постійно використовували слово `комірка` в контексті таблиць. Позаяк це одиниця збереження інформації (знову ж в контексті таблиць) відповідно комірка (як похідне від комірчини) підходить краще.

Comment: @BohdanKuts, я не вважаю коректним вимірювати інформацію в "коморах". Мені здається, що занадто багато уваги приділяється значенню "місце зберігання даних" і ігнорується "A section or compartment of a larger structure"(як влучно, але знову ж таки мимохідь зазначив @Chizh). Чомусь ніхто не називає аркуш в MS Word коморою, льохом... хоча це теж місце зберігання текстових даних, чи не так? А от клітинка чітко відображає  сутність - елемент, який знаходиться на перетині рядка і стовпця; елемент більш складної структури; об'єкт прямокутної форми

Comment: А тут ніхто і не пропонує обраховувати інформацію в "коморах". До речі, в дійсності _A section or compartment of a larger structure_ далеко не завжди відповідає реальному стану справ. Аркуш в MS Word має аналогію лише із книгою/зошитом і ця аналогія - первинна, її немає чим замінити (адекватно). Таблиці ж в ІТ мають аналогію з базами даних, які в свою чергу (грубо кажучи) використовуються для збереження та управління цими даними. "Форма" елементу немає значення. Значення має, вибачте за тавтологію, лише призначення цього елементу.

Comment: Ніхто не забороняє вам називати `cell` клітинкою, але загальноприйнятий варіант саме `комірка`.

Comment: @Bohdan Kuts, я вам теж не нав'язую свою думку, але ви самі зазначили, що "[комірка] - це одиниця збереження інформації (знову ж в контексті таблиць)". 2. Хоча бази даних і мають багато спільного з електронними таблицями, та все ж не варто їх ототожнювати. Наприклад, чи зможете ви в класичну базу даних "в клітинку/комірку А1 ввести формулу =A2+A3", чи "змінити формат клітинки/комірки А5 з текстового на числовий". Щодо "форми", так, це не принципово, але маленький бонус

Comment: Визнаю - нечітко описав поняття. Згідний - електронні таблиці це не бази даних і поведінка в них інша. Продовжувати суперечку не бачу сенсу. Використрвуйте те, що Вам зручніше - головне, щоб інші розуміли що саме Ви маєте не увазі.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

З суб'єктивної точки зору мені подобаються обидва варіанти.

Звернемось за допомогою до тлумачного словника:

[КОМІ́РКА, и, жін.](http://sum.in.ua/s/komirka)

1. Зменш. до **комора**. — *В комірці біля гаража ви знайдете все потрібне (Юрій Смолич, I, 1958, 58); Платон рвучко метнувся до комірки й за момент повернувся з пузатою пляшечкою (Олесь Досвітній, Вибр., 1959, 218).*
2. Маленьке, тісне приміщення; **кімнатка**. *Комірка.. була маленька, збита з дощок і обліплена глиною (Іван Франко, VII, 1951, 344); Він забрався в свою комірку і ліг на дерев'яний тапчан (Натан Рибак, Що сталося.., 1947, 124).*
3. **Заглиблення**, ямка; гніздо. *Вона була така наївна і така хитра, так мало і так багато знала, як та мурашка, що будує пишні палати і живе в темних комірках (Михайло Коцюбинський, II, 1955, 214); На столах лежали скриньки з безліччю клітинок. Очевидно, то були окремі комірки для літер (Ірина Вільде, Сестри.., 1958, 110);* Невеликий отвір, вічко (у системі подібних). *Перед сівбою насіння сої пропускали на решета з довгастими комірками 4,5 міліметра завширшки (Колгоспник України, 4, 1959, 26); Сотова комірка.*

[КЛІТИ́НКА, и, жін.](http://sum.in.ua/s/klitynka)

Зменш.-пестл. до **клітина**. *О земле моя, мій ти світе, тобою душа вся сія! З тобою згадками я злитий, як кожна клітинка моя (Володимир Сосюра, Солов. далі, 1957, 161); Марко розірвав конверт і витяг з нього аркуш паперу в клітинку (Іван Микитенко, II, 1957, 488).*

[КЛІТИ́НА, и, жін.](http://sum.in.ua/s/klityna)

1. Найпростіша **одиниця будови організму**, яка складається з протоплазми, ядра та оболонки. *Відомо, що протоплазма, ядро та оболонка утворюють клітину (Зоологія. Підручник для 7 кл., 1957, 6); Весною сосна найбуйніше росте — відкладаються нові клітини, вона росте в товщину й угору (Юрій Яновський, II, 1958, 124).*
2. Те саме, що **клітка 3.** *Вбиралася Марина в коротку спідничку до колін.., а кохтинку носила картату, з «шотландки», червоних і зелених клітин (Юрій Смолич, Мир.., 1958, 44); Від того місця і майже до кінця яру дно його посічене великими шаховими клітинами. То — .. калюжі-ставки (Юрій Мушкетик, Серце.., 1962, 191).*
3. Те саме, що **клітка 1.** *Він так і протиратиме штани в темній клітині біля прийомної свого шефа (Натан Рибак, Час, 1960, 494).*

[КЛІ́ТКА, и, жін.](http://sum.in.ua/s/klitka)

3. **Чотирикутник** на поверхні чого-небудь, утворений перехресними лініями; кратка (у 1 знач.). *На аркуші з школярського зошита в клітку стояли стовпчики арифметичних прикладів (Юрій Збанацький, Ліс. красуня, 1955, 10).*

З усіх варіантів найкраще підходять варіанти *комірка* в значенні **комора**, а також *клітинка* в значенні ***чотирикутник*** на поверхні чого-небудь, утворений перехресними лініями.

Зі структурної точки зори краще підходить *клітинка*, по змісту, на мій погляд, краще підходить *комірка* в контексті **комора** - **сховище**, де зберігаються ті чи інші продукти, а Excel - це **сховище** даних.

Якщо дивитись з позиції [скевоморфізму](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BA%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%84%D1%96%D0%B7%D0%BC), то краще підходить *клітина*, оскільки можна провести чітку асоціацію зошитів в клітинку з електронними таблицями.

*Словник української мови: в 11 томах. — Том 4, 1973. — Стор. 185.*

Comment: Комірка у мене чомусь більше асоціюється із коморою, відповідно, консервами і закрутками, а не чимось пов'язаним із розрахунками

Comment: Колись чув ["чарунка"](http://sum.in.ua/s/charunka) в значенні місця збереження інформації в контексті електроних таблиць.

Comment: @OlexandrMatviienko, `cell` - це місце, в якому _зберігаються_ дані (цільна одиниця даних). І ці дані можна використовувати для розрахунків. Тобто, я веду до того, що кращим варіантом на мою думку є саме `комірка` як _місце для збереження даних_.

Comment: @sashaeve, аналогію із зошитом вдасться проводити лише до того моменту, поки таблиця буде двомірна. Якщо ж вона стане n-мірною - таку аналогію вже так просто не проведеш. А зростаюча складність даних та вдосконалені методи їх опрацювання ведут до такої зміни також.

Comment: @BohdanKuts, саме тому зараз більшість компаній (Microsoft, Google, Apple) відмовляються від скевоморфізму - прив'язки інтерфейсів та термінів до реального світу. Тому і "комірка" мені подобається більше через асоціацію зі сховищем, місцем для збереження чогось.

Comment: Мені здається ви не відповіли на питання, а трошки розширили його. Взагалі у технічних вишах та коледжах використовується термін комірка. Відповідно він є більш сталим і в іт сфері на даний час.

Answer (score 1):

[Результати](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/cell) невеличкого етимологічного дослідження показують що *cell* походить:

> From Middle English celle, selle, from Old English *cella (attested in inflected forms), from Latin cella ‎(“chamber, small room, compartment”), later reinforced by Anglo-Norman cel, sele, Old French cele.

і поміж іншого має значення

> A section or compartment of a larger structure.

З іншого боку *cell* 'містить' у собі *щось*. Подібне наводить на аналогію з приміщенням для зберігання.

в українській мові є слово [*льох*](http://sum.in.ua/s/ljokh) яке поміж іншого вживається у значенні

> 1. Спеціально обладнана яма із східцями для зберігання продуктів (переважно овочів і фруктів). //  Таке приміщення, що використовується для переховування або ув'язнення кого-небудь. //  Приміщення в землі, обладнане для зберігання вина або боєприпасів, пороху тощо.

Моя *Гіпотеза 1* полягає в тому, що користувачі краще запам'ятовують **ідіоми** ніж повні аналогії

Моя *Гіпотеза 2* полягає в тому, що користувачі надають перевагу **більш коротшим** словам ніж довшим

Зважаючи на зазначені гіпотези, можна запропонувати українське слово *льох* як достатньо точний відповідник

1. Певним чином зберігається сенс явища
2. Воно коротке і односкладове так само, як і термін який необхідно запозичити

Comment: Без образ, але, якщо брати до уваги тільки "місце зберігання", то тоді ще можна додати кошик, миска, горнятко... - це все крайнощі

Comment: Про варіант перекладу "A section or compartment of a larger structure" ви згадали тільки мимохідь і проігнорували надалі, хоча, на мою думку, - це саме те, що відповідає контексту уживання

Comment: Комірок як правило багато в будь якому житлі, а льох це величезне сховище, як правило одне. Тому комірка підходить більше. Крім того цей термін вже сталий, в тому числі у вишах.