# Як перекласти "лестничная клетка"?

Tags: переклад, from-russian

Який переклад словосполучення <sub>рос.</sub> ***лестничная клетка*** вважається усталеним в українській мові?

Попередній пошук виявив, мʼяко кажучи, широке різноманіття пропонованих варіантів:

- *сходо́ва кліти́на* — Російсько-український словник технічної термінології 1928р. (І. Шелудько, Т. Садовський) ([PDF, стор. 127](https://r2u.org.ua/data/%D0%A0%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%96%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE-%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%97%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9%20%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%20%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%85%D0%BD%D1%96%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%97%20%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BC%D1%96%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%96%D1%97%20%281928%29.pdf))
- *сходова́ клітка* — [СУМнозвісний СУМ](http://sum.in.ua/s/skhodovyj) (наголос вказано лише у чол. роді, але жін. відповідник також має мати наголос на останній склад)
- *сходова́ клітина* — також СУМ, на підставі того, що [клітина](http://sum.in.ua/s/klityna).3 — те саме, що [клітка](http://sum.in.ua/s/klitka).1, вказана у попередньому пункті
- *сходова́ кліть* — [Російсько-український народний сучасний словник 2009–](https://r2u.org.ua/s?w=%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9&scope=rusb&main_only=on&dicts=10)
- *сходова клітка* — Google Translate
- *сходова площадка* — [Вікіпедія](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8)

  > *Сходи складаються з маршів і **площадок**.*
- *сходовий майданчик* —  [Вікіпедія](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BA)

  > *Сходовий майданчик — рівне місце, поміст між маршами сходів.*
- *сходовий майданчик* — [Олександр Пономарів](http://ponomariv-kultura-slova.wikidot.com/synonimy#toc57):

  > Зменшене від *майдан* — *майданчик* уживається зі значенням «місце для певних робіт, ігор, спортивних тренувань, танців тощо»:
  > *будівельний майданчик, дитячий майданчик, спортивний майданчик, танцювальний майданчик, **сходовий майданчик***.
  > Подеколи використовуване в цих випадках слово *площадка* **є непотрібним запозиченням з російської мови** (бо в українській не існує *площадь* і відсутній суфікс `-дка`).<sup>(1)</sup>

---

Отже, маємо [декартів добуток](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D1%96%D0%B2_%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%83%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BA_%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%BD) двох множин:

- Наголос у прикметнику: *сходо́ва* або *сходова́*
- Іменник: *кліть, клітка, клітина, площадка, майданчик*

**Як, урешті-решт, правильно?**

---

<sup>(1)</sup> Не питайте в мене, звідки проф. Пономарів взяв суфікс `-дка`, якщо там цілком питомий суфікс `-ка`.

See also:

- [Переклад на українську мову "cell" в контексті електронних таблиць](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/q/362/)

Comment: *Площадка* походить від *площа*. Отже суфіксом є `-дка`, а не `-ка`, як у російській.

Comment: на мою думку, краще всього передасть ідею словосполучення `сходовий каркас`

Comment: @chizh чому каркас?

Comment: @Yola а чому `клетка`? я так підозрюю, що на кресленні каркас будівлі виглядає як [`клітина`](http://vignette4.wikia.nocookie.net/runescape2/images/6/6c/Steel_cage_trapped_player.png/revision/latest?cb=20150913170713) (картинка по запиту "cage" у гугл) і та частина яка містить сходи іменується в російській мові `лестнечной`

Comment: @chizh `клетка` зазвичай паралепіпедна, а каркас може бути, скажімо, трикутним.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Варто розрізняти *"лестничную клетку"* (stairwell), *"лестничную площадку"* (stair landing) та *"лестничный марш"* чи *"лестничный пролет"* (stairway або flight of stairs).

> [Лестничная клетка](https://construction_materials.academic.ru/5082) – помещение высотой в два этажа или более, занятое лестницей.

Або (там само):

> Лестничная клетка – вертикальный проем в перекрытиях здания, предназначенный для монтажа лестничных маршей.

Мій переклад:

> Сходова клітка - приміщення висотою два поверхи і вище, у якому розміщено сходи.
>
> Сходова клітка - вертикальна пройма у перекриттях будівель, призначена для монтажу сходових маршів.

Переклала саме як ***клітка***, зважаючи на [словник Шелудька-Садовського](https://r2u.org.ua/s?w=%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0&scope=all&dicts=4&highlight=on), на який посилається автор запитання. Я зрозуміла те скорочення "к." як таке, що означає "клітка", а не "клітина":

[image]

Ну і [СУМ](http://sum.in.ua/s/klitka) подає:

> Сходова клітка — місце в будинку для сходів.

На [Народний сучасний словник](https://r2u.org.ua/s?w=%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0&scope=all&dicts=10&highlight=on) (з його варіантом *"кліть"*) я б не покладалася - наскільки я розумію, свій переклад там може запропонувати будь-хто.

> [Лестничная площадка](https://architect.academic.ru/3364/%D0%9B%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%89%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%BA%D0%B0) - площадка между лестничными пролетами.

Переклала як:

> Сходовий майданчик - майданчик між сходовими прогонами.

***Прогін*** взяла [ось тут](https://e2u.org.ua/s?w=flight&dicts=15&highlight=on&filter_lines=on). ***Майданчик*** - за порадою проф. Пономарева, яку цитував автор.

Нарешті:

> [Лестничный марш](https://construction_materials.academic.ru/5086/%D0%9B%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%88) – непрерывная часть вертикальной лестницы
>
> - между зоной для входа и схода, если лестницы без площадок, или
> - между зоной для входа или схода и ближайшей площадкой, или
> - между площадками для отдыха, следующими друг за другом.

Переклад:

> Сходовий марш - суцільна частина сходів
>
> - між зоною для входу і сходження, якщо сходи без майданчиків, або
> - між зоною для входу чи сходження і найближчим майданчиком, або
> - між майданчиками для відпочинку, що ідуть один після одного.

***"Марш"*** маємо у [СУМі](http://sum.in.ua/s/marsh) (значення 4).

Якщо я правильно зрозуміла, то *марш* і *прогін* - приблизно те саме. Хоча мені видається, що *марш* (stairway) стосується самих сходів, що у нас під ногами, а *прогін* (flight of stairs) - простору між сходовими майданчиками.

**Отож, *лестничная клетка* - це *сходова клітка***.

Answer (score 3):

[image]
Мова — ДНК нації рекомендує вживати *сходовИй майданчик.*
Такої ж думки притримується Олександр Авраменко, доцент Київського університету імені Бориса Грінченка, у своєму [відеоуроці](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SoJu9nXQPpI).

Comment: Дякую за відповідь. Думаю, що тут проблема трошки незвична. Якщо ви помітили, автор запитання провів деяку попередню роботу і навів деякі джерела, у тому числі, і досить поважні. І вони усі мають різну відповідь на запитання. Так от, постає проблема поважності джерел, і я сильно не упевнений, що сайт «Мова — ДНК нації» і  доц. Авраменко — то є більш поважні джерела, аніж Шелудько-Садовський або СУМ.

Comment: Зрозуміло. Надалі буду більш ретельніше читати питання. Дякую.