# Як перекласти "ячейка общества"?

Tags: переклад, from-russian

В мережі знайшла декілька варіантів:
чарунка суспільства, ланка суспільства та осередок суспільства. Яких з них правильний?

Якщо перекладати "ячейка" як компютерний термін, то це "комірка".

Comment: Ну, чудова ж була тема для запитання, можна ж було провести власне дослідження і написати гарне запитання, яке продемонструвало б суперечності між різними джерелами і за рахунок цього набрало б мішок плюсів.

Comment: Компʼютерні терміни перекладають з тієї мови, якою їх назвали автори, і там  [не лише «комірка»](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/q/362/).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Це такий поширений радянський штамп, що навіть важко уявити що в українській літературі радянських часів він не залишив слідів.

У словнику СУМ http://sum.in.ua/s/Sim.ja, здається такий слід знайшовся: "Сім'я в нашому суспільстві — це первісний осередок багатогранних людських відносин — господарських, моральних, духовно-психологічних, естетичних. І, звичайно, виховних (Радянська Україна, 11.I 1969, 4);"

Якщо взяти радянську формулу (а насправді її автор - Огюст Конт, засновник соціології як науки) "[Семья́ — базовая ячейка общества](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8C%D1%8F)", то з наведеної цитати виходить:

> Сім'я - первісний осередок суспільства

Подібний варіант можна знайти у ком'юніті [ua-mova](https://ua-mova.livejournal.com/758058.html).

Проте [російсько-український народний сучасний словник](https://r2u.org.ua/s?w=%D1%8F%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%BA%D0%B0&highlight=on) пропонує такі варіанти:

> ячейка общества – ланка суспільства, суспільна одиниця;

Проте цей словник створюється командою редакторів сайту https://r2u.org.ua, тому наскільки авторитетним його вважати - питання відкрите.

Підручник "Соціологія: Навчальний посібник. - Дворецька Г.В. - КНЕУ 2002" також [містить](http://politics.ellib.org.ua/pages-3005.html) слово "осередок":

> Сім’я — головний осередок суспільства. Вона відіграє надзвичайну роль у його життєдіяльності — через фізичну й соціокультурну зміну поколінь забезпечує мож­ливість існування суспільства.